# Getting all hard-coded paths out of the code, how to handle the config file?

Tags: python, config

I'm trying to get all my hard coded paths out of one of my projects and into a config.ini file. The only thing left is the config file itself. Since I have to read it in:

```
>>> config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
>>> configReader = config.read('config.ini')
```

I don't know how to get this out of the code (or if it's even possible). So is there a way to get the hardcoded config path out of the code?

Comment: If you are planning on releasing this for Linux platforms, you might want to check the XDG Base Directory specification, and pyxdg - http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: It's going to be both linux and windows, thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the path to a module by using `__file__`:

```
#config.py
pass
```

Importing the module lets you access the name of the file it was imported from:

```
#main.py
import os
import config

print config.__file__
print os.path.basename(config.__file__)
print os.path.dirname(config.__file__)
```

Running this in a console gives:

```
>>> import main
C:/Users/peterwood/Desktop\config.py
config.py
C:/Users/peterwood/Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a command line parameter that specifies where your program can find your configuration file.

Take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html and it's newer brother http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html on how to parse command line parameters in Python.

Comment: I want it to work as a python package, not a commandline tool

Comment: Then have the user of the Python package pass in the location of the configuration file, as required, which they most likely will be getting from the end-user through a parameter passed in upon start of the process.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to get this out of the code (or if it's even
>   possible).

Not possible AFAIK. The program has to know what file to read somehow. There is nothing wrong with having a hard-coded path of the config file in your program.